# How to say 'I want to be red' in Japanese?

Tags: translation, adjectives

`Watasi wa akaku sitai.` ?
`Watasi wa akakaritai.` ?

How to say 'Be red!'?

`Akaku siro!`  ?
`Akakare!`  ?

How to say 'It's being red at the moment (as in: it will turn purple and then blue soon)'?

`Kore wa akaku site iru tadaima.`  ?
`Kore wa akakarete iru tadaima.`  ?

For na-adjectives:

How to say 'Be polite!'

`Teinei ni siro!`   ?
`Teinei nare!`    ?

And how to say 'He's being polite (as in: he's usually not but in order to get what he wants, he's being polite at the moment).'?

`Kare wa teinei ni site iru.`   ?
`Kare wa teinei narete iru.`   ?

Comment: While your questions are not inappropiate because you have done your own research (good!!) and come up with your translated sentences, I see from your profile that most of your questions in here are requests for help with translations. Therefore, I kindly suggest you to give a try to the site https://lang-8.com which has been particularly created with the purpose of getting corrected your translations by native speakers of a language. I find both sites Stackexchange and Lang-8 are complementary and very useful, each one serving its own purpose.

Comment: ^ でも・・ Lang-8 は、ここ数年、新規登録停止になってるんです。。

Comment: Looks like HiNative is the successor website to Lang-8 -- https://hinative.com/ -- they appear to be taking new user registrations.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the context (if you don't provide more, we cannot help much), but in some cases you might use:
- Be red! 赤くなれ！
- It's being red at the moment 現在赤です。
- Be polite! 丁寧に話せ！
- He's being polite 今だけ丁寧に喋りやがっている

Comment: `喋りやがっている` <-- ううん・・　「しゃべっ**ていやがる** 」「しゃべっ**てやがる** 」って言います。

Comment: I meant to use the construct explained in this article as "In order to use 「やがる」, you simply attach it to the stem of the verb":
  http://www.guidetojapanese.org/casual.html#part8 - are you referring to another usage of やがる that has a different meaning?

Comment: (I had in mind the consecrated example, https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/勝手にしやがれ)

Comment: 「する」＋「やがる」は、「しやがる」です。（命令形は「しやがれ」であってます。）「している」＋「やがる」は、「していやがる」/「してやがる」です。（「しやがっている」 is incorrect.）「しゃべる」＋「やがる」は、「しゃべりやがる」です。「しゃべっている」＋「やがる」は、「しゃべっていやがる」/「しゃべってやがる」です。（「しゃべりやがっている」 is incorrect.）

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice this (I thought usage was like in colloquial sentence "何しやがってんの" that I thought I heard a relative using in the past). Your assertions seem consistent with explanations from https://kotobank.jp/word/やがる-647625